# How to handle multiple checkboxes in ASP.NET WEb Form and Code-Behind File

Tags: asp.net

**Here is the Code in the .aspx web form** What is the best way to handle a group of multiple checkboxes.

```
 <input id="nonunionexempt" type="checkbox" value="0"       name="employeeType" tabindex="8" runat="server" />

<input id="nonexempthourly" type="checkbox" value="1" name="employeeType" tabindex="9" />

<input id="eleven99" type="checkbox" value="2" name="employeeType" tabindex="10" />

<input id="nysna" type="checkbox" value="3" name="employeeType" tabindex="11" />

<input id="cir" type="checkbox" value="4" name="employeeType" tabindex="12" />
```

**Here is the code behind file** Is there a better way to deal with multiple checkboxes?

```
  protected void SaveEmployee()
     {
         Employee model = new Employee();

         if (nonunionexempt.Checked)
         {
            model.EmployeeType = nonunionexempt.Value;
         }
         if (nonunionexempt.Checked)
         {
            model.EmployeeType = nonexempthourly.Value;
         }

          IValueProvider provider = new  FormValueProvider(ModelBindingExecutionContext);
         if (TryUpdateModel<Employee>(model, provider))
         {
             LoaRepository.saveData(model);               
         }
        else
        {
            throw new FormatException("Could not model bind");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Better? Just curious what does that mean to you? Seems like pretty readable and straightforward code to me.

Comment: There are over 15 checkboxes. Just wondering in there is better solution than just using if statement for each checkbox. thanks.

Comment: you have a copy/paster error - second if

Comment: off the top of my head - make the whole thing event driven,  by the time you call SaveEmployee you should just be grabbing values, not necessarily checking conditions of checkboxes.  Employee should be updated onclick in some object clientside that mimics employee or serverside on each click.  You'll have to figure out how best to implement that.  Keep in mind that serverside implementation will need some type of persistance.

Comment: WIth runat=server and the Asp.net webforms paradigm, I think you really do not want to go that way. It seems just fine to me. Persistance comes with viewstate.

Comment: as there could be only one `EmployeeType` what you really need is a `RadioButtonList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code sounds good and clean. But if I were you I would use web controls instead of HTML ones. Also, I don't think there is a need to write the if statements even if not using web controls. Simply assign the 'checked' property which is of value true or false. Finally, if embedding the check boxes in a web user control then in the case of multiple usages this could bring a valuable help and of course better maintenance. Hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the ASP.NET Checkbox control instead of input tags, you won't need the if statements. In code behind use checkBoxID.Checked property which will return true or false.